# JavaScript event handler not working

Tags: javascript, html, events, handlers

This javascript:

```
window.onload=init;

function init(){
    var addSongButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
    addSongButton.onclick = handleAddSongButtonClick;
}

function handleAddSongButtonClick(){
    var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
    var songName = textInput.value;

    if(songName=""){
        alert("Please enter a song name");
    }
    else{
    alert("Adding " +songName);
    }
}
```

is linked to this HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="songTextInput" size="40" placeholder="Song name">
  <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Song">
</form>

<ul id="playlist">

</ul>
```

Why whenever I enter a song name or don't enter a song name it just alerts "Adding"? I want it to alert "Adding *insert song name*" when text is entered and alert "Please enter a song name" when text is not entered.

Comment: Can you show us in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: im relatively new to coding especially javascript, what is jsFiddle?

Comment: JSFiddle is a tool so you can put your code in a working demo.  It helps us to be able to play around with your code and test it.

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x6AYz/).

Comment: wow thats a great tool thanks guys

Comment: I personally prefer [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You are using an equals sign in your `if()` check, here:

```
if(songName=""){
```

That is setting `songName' to be an empty string.  Change the code to:

```
if (songName === "") {
```

. . . and that should do the comparison correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the assignment operator, `=`, in your if statement:

```
if(songName="")
```

where you should be using either `==` or `===` to actually compare the values. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for the difference between these)

What's happening currently is that `songName=""` is being evaluated, and returns `""` (the value that was assigned). This is a falsey value meaning it is interpreted as `false` and so your coniditonal statement is falling through to your `else` but with `songName` now being equal to the empty string.